# split a column in Scala

Tags: scala

Hi I am trying to split a column in spark.

Data set sample:

[twitter data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APVhZ.png)

Here I want to split the Month column to a Month and a year:
Example:

2019 10

2009 11

and further count all the tweets in a year.(I know how to use reduceByKey(*+*) here)

How do I split columns in Spark? I don't want to use Data frames.

Comment: You can use `map` function, split the string by length (year is first 4 chars, month is next two) and return a tuple of `(month, year)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as follow

```
val rdd = oldRdd.map({case(tokenType,month,count,hashTagName) => (tokenType,month.substring(0,4),month.substring(2,6),count,hashTagName)})
```